# How to nest enum

Tags: java, enums

I have some UI client filters (combobox and checkbox group) that I need to use on server side: I thought to use an enum to identify filter types and others enums to identify each filter's options.

```
// All UI filters
public enum FilterType {
    AGGREGATION("aggregation"),
    AREA("area"),
    PRODUCTION("production"), 
    DATA_TYPE("datatype"),
    PRODUCER("producer"),
    NETWORK("network"),
    SOURCE("source");

    private String value;

    private FilterType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

// FilterType.AGGREGATION filter options
public enum AggregationOptionType {
    STANDARD("standard"),
    DTR("dtr"),
    CO("co");

    private String value;

    private AggregationOptionType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I would like to craete a hard link between `FilterType.AGGREGATION` and `AggregationOptionType` forcing the access to an option via `FilterType.AGGREGATION.DTR`.

How can I "nest" an enum inside a value of another enum?
Are there other patterns (maybe smarter than mine) to achieve the same result?

**EDIT**

A clarification: I do **NOT** need to assign to each value of the outer enum a value of a common inner enum. I need to assign a whole different inner enum to each value of the outer enum.

Comment: Just declare a field of type `AggregationOptionType` inside `FilterType`.

Comment: The easiest way would be to extend `FilterType` with the enums `STANDARD_AGGREGATION`, `DTR_AGGREGATION` and `CO_AGGREGATION` because nesting is not possible. Otherwise, you could create "normal" objects, possibly using the singleton design pattern - as enums are singletons by default. This way you would have gained typesafety and more flexibility.

Comment: But `AggregationOptionType` still exists as separate enum: I would link to enclose it inside its `FilterType` option

Comment: If I understand correctly, `AggregationOptionType` only applies to `FilterType.AGGREGATION` and *not* `FilterType.AREA` or anything else?

Comment: `enums` provide unmodifiable behavior, but IFAIU you want `FilterTypes` beeing combined with `AggregationTypes` I'd do this when creating a concrete filter Object: `new Filter(FilterType.AGGREGATION, AggregationOptionType.DTR);`

Comment: @Smutje: yes you're right

Comment: if you really want to nest them, search for: user:51292 nested enums

Answer (score 2):

You can put one enum into another, like:

```
enum OuterEnum {
  A, B;    
  enum InnerEnum {
    C, D;
  }
}
```

To use like:

```
class Enumuser {
  OuterEnum.InnerEnum ie = OuterEnum.InnerEnum.C; 
}
```

But of course, that is not exactly what you are looking for.
You need to go one step further:

```
enum OuterEnum {
  A(InnerEnum.C), B(InnerEnum.D);

   private final InnerEnum inner;

   private OuterEnum(InnerEnum inner) { this.inner = inner; }

   public InnerEnum getInner() { return inner; }

  enum InnerEnum {
      C, D;
  }
}

class Enumuser {
  OuterEnum.InnerEnum inner = OuterEnum.A.getInner(); 
}
```

But a final word of *warning*: don't get too hang up on using enums for such purposes. You see, as soon as you start writing switch statements all over the place that switch over such enums, in order to do this or that ... you are probably doing something *wrong*. Consider **not** "falling into that enum *trap*" please.

Instead you should be looking into using **polymorphism**, like shown [here](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)!

Comment: I agree with you about polymorphism, but in my situation I just need enums not to put logic on strings `value`. I think your answer is on the right direction: how could I generalise it to se a different `InnerEnum` for each `OuterEnum` option?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the Enum, as a variable. 
But only if you can have all the sub Enums under the same enum type ie

```
public enum FilterType {
    AGGREGATION("aggregation",Subfilter.DTR);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it in the same way like a `String value` and if you want to have a single file, so hold your enums in a interface class:

```
public interface Enums {

    public enum FilterType {
        AGGREGATION("aggregation", AggregationOptionType.DTR),
        AREA("area"),
        PRODUCTION("production"),
        DATA_TYPE("datatype"),
        PRODUCER("producer"),
        NETWORK("network", AggregationOptionType.CO),
        SOURCE("source");

        public final String                value;
        public final AggregationOptionType type;

        private FilterType(String value, AggregationOptionType typy) {
            this.value = value;
            this.type = typy;
        }

        private FilterType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.type = AggregationOptionType.STANDARD;
        }

    }

    public enum AggregationOptionType {
        STANDARD("standard"),
        DTR("dtr"),
        CO("co");

        public final String value;

        private AggregationOptionType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like as follows:

```
//All UI filters
public interface FilterType {
     // FilterType.AGGREGATION
     public interface AGGREGATION {
          // FilterType.AGGREGATION filter options
        enum AggregationOptionType {
           STANDARD("standard"), 
           DTR("dtr"), 
           CO("co");

           private String value;

           private AggregationOptionType(String value) {
               this.value = value;
           }

           public String getValue() {
               return value;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

e.g. for AGGREGATION